# Background transparent not working JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx

Hello I have an popup like this :

[image]

The problem is I have the background white back the border-radius like in the picture.

I have the CSS like this :

```
.anchorPanePopUpError {
    -fx-border-color: #BDC3C7;
    -fx-border-width: 5px;
    -fx-border-radius: 30px;
    -fx-background-radius: 30px;
}
```

And I have not the problem on my computer but in an other computer althought the Java version is the same.

Help please.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but have you tried adding CSS property like this: `-fx-background-color: rgba(248, 248, 247, 0.5);`?

Comment: You don't show us code, how I understand in background is your scene. Try to make it transparent as scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: The white corners are the background of one of the parent nodes. If it is popup stage, you can do what @GVArt proposes: make the scene of the popup stage transparent.

Comment: I have in my code 'scene.setFille(Color.TRANSPARENT);' and not working.

Comment: It's possible that the OS not supported transparent ? because in an other computer, it's working

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem today, when you create the stage you need to use setStageStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT). You might have it set to UNDECORATED

Answer (score 0):

The fix should be relatively simple, first thing would be to discover which node has white background.

Before moving forward, your node probably already is transparent, but it looks white due to your Scene which is always white. You can check that with this code:

```
scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

If everything do not becomes transparent, it means that something still has its default background color, white. In order to change it, use this code:

```
yourNode.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
```